# Use SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Service Pack 4 with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got SQL Server 2005 Express and I want to use it in setting up the database to be used with Visual Studio 2012. Will they be compatible with each other? Where can I find a good tutorial of how to set them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a SQL Server 2005 to test with but I don't see why they should not be compatible. The native driver for SQL Server did some major changes in the 2005 version, but I think you will be fine connecting even if you are using VS 2012.

My assumption is that there really should not be any need to change your code if you are using SQL 2012 or SQL 2005 Express, the basic T-SQL are the same. But if you are considering using e.g. Entity Framework (EF) then you may run into issues and check compatibility.

As for installation I think both of them are stright forward. Next-next-finish...

When you test connectivity look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005 for examples of connection strings.

Comment: It is compatible but not the best choice so I installed SQL Server Express 2012 and now everything is working correctly.